# Problems about reading tfrecord with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Now my problem is about reading tfrecords.
For example, assume I have two image, and  each box has its boundingbox to include objects.

```
    image1    bbox1:xmin1,ymin1,xmax1,ymax1
    image2    bbox2:xmin2,ymin2,xmax2,ymax2
```

The datas have been write to tfrecord file sucessfully,now my job is to read it.

And when I load it, I find the data is not matched.For example it may be

```
`image1   bbox2:xmin2,ymin2,xmax2,ymax2`
```

I try to draw it using opencv2 and find this problem.

My code to read tfrecord is as follow:

```
    image, gbboxes= tf.train.batch(
            [image, gbboxes],
            batch_size=config.batch_size,
            num_threads=1,
            capacity=50)

        batch_queue = slim.prefetch_queue.prefetch_queue(
            [image, gbboxes],
            capacity=50)

        image, gbboxes = batch_queue.dequeue()

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
            init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            sess.run(init_op)
            # 0 index to extreact first image of batch
            image = sess.run(image[0, :, :, :])
            gbboxe = sess.run(gbboxes[0, :])

            [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] = gbboxe*config.image_width
            image = np.asarray(image, np.uint8)
            cv2.rectangle(image, (int(xmin), int(ymin)), (int(xmax), int(ymax)), (0, 255, 0), 1)
            cv2.imshow("test", image)
            cv2.waitKey()      
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is fine, you get the mismatch because you do this:

```py
image = sess.run(image[0, :, :, :])
gbboxe = sess.run(gbboxes[0, :])
```

Every time you call `sess.run()` the graph is evaluated **on a new input** and whatever tensor you pass in the arguments is computed and its value is returned. 
If you want the image and the bbox from the same sample, run

```py
image, gbboxe = sess.run([image[0, :, :, :], gbboxes[0, :]])
```